# Multiple client socket messages

Tags: sockets, tcp, client-server, protocols

Is it possible to continue receiving socket messages after the host has stopped sending? Our client seems to be looping the socket messages (getting the same one over and over again) even though the host has not sent those messages. The client will get 1000's of messages, while the host has not sent that many.

Comment: No. I highly suspect a bug in your client code.

Comment: what type of bug? In the log files it shows that we receive thousands of messages. What would make it look like we receive that many messages? Sorry, I know that's not great info but I'm not the developer..

Comment: My guess would be that the client isn't checking the return values on one or more of his networking calls (e.g. if recv() fails but the client doesn't check recv()'s return value, the client might proceed to re-examine the buffer that was filled out by an earlier call to recv() and mistakenly think it contained the results of the latest call)

Comment: How did you determine that the client got these messages? Be as specific as you possibly can. (For example, "a call to `recv` returned a positive value" would be sufficiently specific.)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this cant really happen. So as the commenters said, a bug in the client or the server is highly likely.

I'd suggest using [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) to sniff what happens on the wire.

If the data is actually seen on the wire multiple times, then review your server code. Otherwise have a look at the client. If your programs run on normal windows/linux/mac computers, you can do the sniffing directly on one of those machines.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to continue receiving socket messages after the host has stopped sending?

No.

> Our client seems to be looping the socket messages (getting the same one over and over again)

In other words it is ignoring the return code of `recv()` or whatever API it is using to read, so it keeps reusing the same buffer contents even after end of file or a terminal error.

> even though the host has not sent those messages. The client will get 1000's of messages, while the host has not sent that many.

The client won't *receive* even *one* excess message, but there are plenty of ways in which it can buggily *print* excess messages.

Comment: Something like this seemed to fix the issue. Thank you for the response.